# Get HTML form arrays into PHP loop

Tags: php, html

I have a simple form with a array of fields, I want to associate a unique number to each field and grab it in a PHP loop, eg:

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="survey[][5]">
  <input type="text" name="survey[][43]">

  <input type="submit" name="submit" type="submit"/>
</form>

$fields = $_POST['survey'];
foreach($fields as $f)
{ 

   var_dump ($f);

}
```

The above PHP doesnt help me get the unique value, how would I do this? I need to get the string from the field and unique value in one loop.

If I do a var_dump I get this array(1) { [4]=> string(18) "stuff from field 1" } array(1) { [5]=> string(18) "stuff from field 2" } array(1) { [6]=> string(18) "stuff from field 3" }

Comment: What have you tried? Have you attempted to echo whatever object your $f is?

Comment: I do a var_dump and get this array(1) { [4]=> string(18) "stuff from field 1" } array(1) { [5]=> string(18) "stuff from field 2" } array(1) { [6]=> string(18) "stuff from field 3" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing it like that, you are pushing a value into an array index that is in an array, I think you want something like this:

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="survey[5]">
  <input type="text" name="survey[43]">

  <input type="submit" name="submit" type="submit"/>
</form>

$fields = $_POST['survey'];
foreach($fields as $unique=>$f)
{ 
   echo $f;
}
```

If you want to do it the way you're doing, you would do it like this

```
foreach($fields as $f)
{        
   //The unique number:
   $unique = key($f); //Since only one element and array pointer is set to this by default
   $value = $f[$unique] //Since only one element in each array you created;
   //The value:
   echo $value;
   //The unique number
   echo $unique
}
```

Comment: the array_pop gives me one string with field input and unique and when echoing $unique nothing is echoed

Comment: Editted my answer, try it and tell me what hapened